# List of products query - Adding the consecutive years condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Stacks! I have a litlle problem with one of my queries. I have a sql query, that shows me list of most popular categories of products overall. It looks like this:

```
    SELECT CategoryName, SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity
FROM ([Order Details]
INNER JOIN Products ON [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID
INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.ProductID = Categories.CategoryID)
GROUP BY CategoryName
ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC;
```

Now, I need to modify it, so it will show me list of categories for each consecutive years. It should cover years 199-1998. I don't want to make a query for each year separately. Is there a way to change this query to show me list of categories for each year?

Comment: I'd do `ORDER BY TotalQuantity DESC`, just to make code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Yeah, I can change that. Still learning SQL so my codes are messy ;p

Comment: Is there a column for year/date in the Order Details table? If yes, we can group it based on that column as well after CategoryName.

Comment: @DEEPAKLAKHOTIA I should've mention that, I am using old Northwind database. Yes, there is one column worth mentioning in [Orders] named OrderDate.

Comment: @DEEPAKLAKHOTIA I think the best way to show the data I need is to show Year/Category/TotalQuantity. There should be 8 rows (8 categories) for each year, 24 rows total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job for you:

```
SELECT Year(OrderDate), CategoryName,  SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity
FROM ([Order Details]
INNER JOIN Products ON [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID
INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.ProductID = Categories.CategoryID)
GROUP BY Year(OrderDate), CategoryName
ORDER BY TotalQuantity DESC;
```

Also, add a filter for date if you're only looking to capture data for specific years. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I had to change some stuff, but it's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CategoryName,datepart(yyyy, [YoutDateCol]) [date], SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity
FROM ([Order Details]
INNER JOIN Products ON [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID
INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.ProductID = Categories.CategoryID)
GROUP BY CategoryName,datepart(yyyy, [YoutDateCol])
ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the other one is more fitting.